# What is default baudrate of serial communication of Octave Arduino Toolkit and how can i configure?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, octave

I tried [Octave Arduino Toolkit](https://octave.sourceforge.io/arduino/index.html) and tried following command.

```
>> pkg load arduino
>> arduinosetup
Running "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino.exe" "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\oct-aiBvJS\octave\octave.in
o"
ans = 1
>> dev = arduino
dev =
  arduino object with fields of:
    port = \\.\COM4
    board = uno
    libraries = {
      i2c
      spi
      servo
      shiftregister
    }
    availablepins = {
      d0 - d13
      a0 - a5
    }
>> val = readVoltage(dev,"A0")
val =  1.9746
```

So i think it is working correctly. But i do not know
Q1. What is default buadrate of COM4
Q2. How can i change the baudrate

Does any body know the answer for Q1 and Q2?

=========

I found `OCTAVE_COMMS_PORT.begin (9600)` in *LiberaryBase.cpp* that seems to configure baudrate. So i changed 9600 to other value.

Compile and write successed but arduino octave does not work correctly.

The error message on Octave is

```
>> dev = arduino("COM4")

error: __initArduino__: failed valid response err=2 - Malformed packet header
error: called from
    __initArduino__ at line 34 column 8
    arduino at line 94 column 16
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the baudrate for the Arduino uno to use in your code, generally the setup block.

```
void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}
```

There's many supported rates and other options (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial.Begin), but unlikely you'll need more than the above line.

Comment: Hello Peter.

I found `OCTAVE_COMMS_PORT.begin (9600)`  and change it. Compile and write successed but Arduino Octave does not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: The default baudrate used by the toolkit is 9600 baud.

Q2: There are two parts to the baudrate used - on the actual arduino AND within the m code running on your computer.

The arduino baudrate is set in +arduinoio/lib/LibraryBase.cpp.

The m file baudrate is set in scanForArduinos.m and @arduino/**initArduino**.m

Not asked here, but I dont think the baudrate is the issue, but it is trying using hardware flow when it shouldnt be.

Try setting after the serial() call in scanForArduinos.m `set(s, 'dataterminalready', 'on');` and @arduino/**initArduino**.m `set(obj.connected, 'dataterminalready', 'on');`